# Android Google Maps V2 enabling 3D ground

Tags: android, google-maps, graphics, 3d, terrain

This is my current code, it's stock from Android Studio Google Maps, except setMapType and setBuildinsEnabled:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
}
```

However I have not been able to get 3D terrain to work nor I haven't found anything useful from Googles documentations.

And I don't mean modeled 3D buildings, I mean this new 3D ground terrain like on todays web Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

currently (and I do think for a long time will be so) Google Maps does not support 3D terrain. Terrain tessellation and elevation models are a bit heavy for a navigation app and are not supported.

You can check alternatives (Javascript engines like Cesium...) or the new Nasa World Wind for Android library. Is currently under active development so it's not finished.